# vi cursor not working properly when line numbers are set

Tags: original-vi

The cursor with !set nu works as !set nonu. Cursor starts on frist character in margin space before the line numbers start instead of first character after line numbers. Cursor on line end will stop where line ends during !set nu

[image: screenshot]

Comment: line numbers aren't part of the buffer. they will go away if  !set nonu was set.

Comment: But you can move the cursor over the numbers? If not, is the cursor stuck to the left? Need more details.

Comment: Also, you tagged both original-vim and original-vi. It can't be both. Which one is it?

Comment: vi. yes. cursor works as if !set nonu was set. editing takes place on location where characters would be if !set nonu was set.

Comment: Okay, original-vi. That's some wacky stuff going on. I'll let someone more familiar with vi chime in (I'm pure vim.)

Comment: this might a terminal issue. Try different terminals and set `$TERM` correctly BTW: what kind of vi are you using? and what exactly did you type to see this?

Comment: @user33030 you keep writing `!set nu`, but the command is spelled with a colon (`:`), not a bang `!`; are you typing a bang or a colon?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Please share more details of your environment, such as which operating system you're on, which terminal emulator, what `vi --version` returns (or similar command to find the version of `vi`) and so on. Can you actually type over those characters with the numbers? What happens if you enter Insert mode with `i` when your cursor is there? Any chance you could record a short screencast to display the behavior you're seeing?